# Invalid distinct with django

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-aggregation, django-annotate

I try to get a cars list on my Django project but i'm in trouble with ORM

```
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

With Car.objects.all() I have a list as:

```
- car#1, user#1
- car#1, user#2
- car#1, user#3
- car#2, user#4
- car#3, user#4
```

what I would like is:

```
- car#1
- car#2
- car#3
```

Then, all cars are distinct by the name, regardless of owner

I've try something like

```
Cars.objects.all().annotate(Count('owner', distinct=True))
```

but I still have all cars. Can someone help me with this point ? Documentation suggests annotate and aggregate but it's still hars to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 Cars.objects.values('name').distinct()
```